# División en sílabas de palabras con -tl- (atlas, atleta etc.)

Tags: pronunciación, sílabas

¿Cómo se separan en sílabas las palabras que tienen la secuencia de consonantes `tl` entre vocales?

Por ejemplo:

- **atlas**: ¿`at-las` o `a-tlas`?
- **atleta**: ¿`at-le-ta` o `a-tle-ta`?
- **decatlón**: ¿`de-cat-lón` o `de-ca-tlón`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La [fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/at-lan-ti-co-o-a-tlan-ti-co-12213/) (asesorada por la RAE) da una explicación de cómo hacerlo:

> El grupo consonántico *-tl-* plantea problemas, porque se pronuncia de forma diferente en distintas zonas hispanohablantes. Dice al respecto el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*:
>
> c) La secuencia de consonantes tl tiende a pronunciarse en sílabas
>   distintas en la mayor parte de la España peninsular y en Puerto Rico:
>   at - las, at - le - ta; en el resto de Hispanoamérica —especialmente
>   en México y en los territorios donde se emplean con cierta frecuencia
>   voces de origen náhuatl, en las que este grupo es inseparable (*tla -
>   co - te*, *cen - zon - tle*)—, en Canarias y en algunas áreas españolas
>   peninsulares, ambas consonantes se pronuncian dentro de la misma
>   sílaba: *a - tlas*, *a - tle - ta*. Teniendo en cuenta estas diferencias,
>   el grupo *tl* podrá separarse o no con guion de final de línea
>   dependiendo de si las consonantes que lo componen se articulan en
>   sílabas distintas o dentro de la misma sílaba: *at- / leta*, *atle- / ta*.
>
> Sin embargo, como señala José Martínez de Sousa en *Ortografía y ortotipografía del español actual* (Gijón: Trea, 2008, pp. 122-123), para evitar que quien pronuncia la palabra que contiene *-tl-* de una forma la encuentre en un texto partida de acuerdo con la otra pronunciación, lo más recomendable es escribir *-tl-* sin separación con la letra anterior ni entre ellas: *Atlán-/ tico*, *atle-/ ta*, *atlas*.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes encontrar una buena explicación sobre la silabación en [este enlace](http://elies.rediris.es/elies4/Fon2.htm). En particular, sobre tu pregunta, esa página dice lo siguiente:

> El ataque complejo está formado por un grupo de */obstruyente/* +
>   */líquida/*, la única combinación consonántica permitida en posición
>   prenuclear en español. **La frontera silábica se situará ante ambas**
>   **consonantes (a-brazo)**, y puede coincidir con la posición inicial de
>   palabra (brazo). Están formados por */p, k, b, g, f/* + */r, l/* y */d, t/*
>   + */r/*. **No consideraremos como tales las combinaciones /tl/ y /dl/**. Aunque la pronunciación varíe, **creemos que el hablante culto, en una
>   dicción cuidada, tiende a marcar la frontera silábica entre los
>   segmentos: atlántico /at.'lan.ti.ko/** (cf. Navarro Tomás, 1918: 98 y
>   156). No obstante, se han de estudiar los americanismos procedentes
>   del náhuatl con el grupo ortográfico *tl*[...]

(cursivas y negritas agregadas por mí).

Buscando por "tl" en el [diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/) encontré esto:

> c) La secuencia de consonantes tl tiende a pronunciarse en sílabas
>   distintas en la mayor parte de la España peninsular y en Puerto Rico:
>   at - las, at - le - ta; en el resto de Hispanoamérica —especialmente
>   en México y en los territorios donde se emplean con cierta frecuencia
>   voces de origen náhuatl, en las que este grupo es inseparable (tla -
>   co - te, cen - zon - tle)—, en Canarias y en algunas áreas españolas
>   peninsulares, ambas consonantes se pronuncian dentro de la misma
>   sílaba: a - tlas, a - tle - ta. Teniendo en cuenta estas diferencias,
>   el grupo tl podrá separarse o no con guion de final de línea
>   dependiendo de si las consonantes que lo componen se articulan en
>   sílabas distintas o dentro de la misma sílaba: at- / leta, atle- / ta.

Answer (score -1):

en México siempre es de la segunda manera

a-tle-ta

Comment: En Argentina también.

Comment: Una respuesta particular a una zona determinada no es general, por su propia definición. La de la Fundeu traída por @lorddarkangel es la más correcta.